# C++ how not to deallocate std::vector data after leaving a scope?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, heap-memory

what I want to do following:

```
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    ...
    result.aData = a.data();
    return result;
}
```

But this obviously deallocates the data when scope ends which I do not want. What I saw that can be done is:

```
{
    std::vector<int> *a = new vector<int>();
    ...
    result.aData = a->data();
    a = nullptr;
    return result;
}
```

But I would like to avoid dynamical allocation, does anyone have any idea how would I do this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Why does `result` have to contain a raw pointer? Who is supposed to own the data?

Comment: But `vector` dynamically allocates its internal storage, so you're not avoiding that anyway. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Easy! `return a;` or `result.a = std::move(a); return result;`

Comment: Why not put a vector in `result`?

Comment: Looks like a typical  [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Hey all, thanks for replying! I am marshalling data from C++ to C# so I need this to be raw pointer. Returning a does not work for me since this struct does not contain only data pointer but some more properties

Comment: @J.Doe Then you probably should use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` and `new T[]` instead of `std::vector<T>`. It allows you to release ownership of allocated chunk. You cannot achieve this with vector.

Comment: I want result to be the owner of memory, I can pass it in if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Don't transfer ownership across language boundaries. The receiving side doesn't know how to free it. Instead accept a span as a parameter and write into that.

Comment: Thank you all, very much! I don't mind having -2, I am really happy because I learned a lot from all of you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are workarounds. However, know that std::vector dynamically allocates memory itself, so fully avoiding it doesn't seem possible.

**One possible workaround:**

Simply fill a vector in your function and return that. What happens is that actually a copy of it will be returned.

So your first example would become:

```
{
std::vector<int> a;
...
return a;
}
```

a will still be deallocated, but its copy will contain everything.

**Another workaround:**

Instead of creating a new vector, have a member vector variable m_vector and use that in the function for calculations.

```
{
// Do something with m_vector
return m_vector;
}
```

No deallocation will happen, but a copy still has to be made. You could return a reference in the function to avoid creation of a copy. 
But returning a reference might potentially screw things up further along the road if multiple instances would want to make use of it.

However... this whole setup sounds like you are trying to solve a problem the wrong way, like a typical XY problem. You might be better off asking for help with your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's it imposible to return raw data from vector and destroy that vector.
You should save vector somewhere for a while or just use raw memory allocation.

Also remember that using raw pointer returned from vector is safe only before first call to any function that modificate vector content.

Second example in your question is memory leak, so don't do that